# Can Angular router expose parent – current – next routes?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have a module which initially redirects to

```
 redirectTo: "/profile/bbb"
```

Where `profile` has two children :

```
{
    path: '',
    component: ProfileComponent,

    children: [{
      path: 'aaa',
      component: AComponent
    }, {
      path: 'bbb',
      component: BComponent
    }]
  }
```

Now - In profile's constructor I  want to know what is the current route (which is `profile`) and what is the next route which it is goint to execute  ( which is `bbb`).

This is the code :

**profile.component.ts**

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    route.children[0].url.subscribe(f => console.log(f))
  }
```

But it shows me  :

[image]

I guess I just queried the structure of the routes rather than the current active route

**Question**

How can I  , in each path along the route , can know what is the parent route ,  current route , and where is it going to navigate ?

*ps I don't want to do it via snapshot solution since component can be reused.*

[**Online Demno**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazyloadedmodulesproblem-urqa5n?file=app%2Fmy-plan%2Fprofile%2Fprofile%2Fprofile.component.ts)

Comment: you going to have the current route using the class ActivatedRoute from the router module, that class will provide you everything that you need

Comment: what do you mean by 'next route'? next as in next in a children array, or next as any other route that the user navigates to?

Comment: @TomaszKula it doesn't have to be a children btw. we can declare route as siblings such as `beatles/john` and `beatles/paul` so paul and john doesn't have to be declared as child routes.  What i want is actually in  ` `/profile/bbb/c/v/b` , if I'm in `c`'s constructor  - then parent is `bbb `and next is `v` . All I want to know is in which part of the route i'm currently at , and who is the parent and what is the next segment that i'm going to to .I'm not talking about user actions here.

Comment: I think your best bet is to parse router.config. But it will not work with lazy loading (loadChildren).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using ActivatedRoute.

Import it like:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

Now inject it in the component:

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log('Parent URL:', route.parent.url['value'][0].path);
    console.log('Child URL:', route.firstChild.url['value'][0].path);
}
```

If you want to know complete URL for every navigation.
Then you can do this by using Router. Probably in AppComponent.

```
import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
```

A component will look like:

```
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((route) => {
        if (route instanceof NavigationStart) {
            console.log("NavigationStart called:", route.url);
        }
        if (route instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            console.log("NavigationEnd called:", route.url);
        }
    });        
  }
```

Comment: Updated  answer.

Comment: Btw you showed parent and child. What about current ? So if  looking at a/b/c  and we're in b's ctor, then can we get b?